# cant move screen content on devices lower then 3.0 android

Tags: android, layout

I need to move the screen content on the left so i use this code
to get the content

```
try {
        content = ((LinearLayout) act.findViewById(android.R.id.content)
                .getParent());
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        /*
         * When there is no title bar
         * (android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"), the
         * android.R.id.content FrameLayout is directly attached to the
         * DecorView, without the intermediate LinearLayout that holds the
         * titlebar plus content.
         */
        content = (FrameLayout) act.findViewById(android.R.id.content);
    }
```

I noticed that on devices with android > 3.0 the content sets in the try block, on devices < 3.0 it goes in the catch block.
Here I move the content:

```
FrameLayout.LayoutParams pr = (android.widget.FrameLayout.LayoutParams) content
                    .getLayoutParams();
            pr.rightMargin = menuSize;
            pr.leftMargin = -menuSize;
            content.setLayoutParams(pr);
```

So on devices >3.0 all works great the content si moved, on devices <3.0 nothing happenes the content just sits with no changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer FrameLayout wont take into consideration the margins if gravity is not set.